# Colors slightly off in "solarized" color scheme

Tags: terminal, colors, emacs

I have installed the [`Solarized` color-theme](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) using `package.el` in the latest version of Emacs (24.3), but the colors seem to be off (the contrast seems to be too low)

My Solarized installation:

[image]

The screenshot from the website:

[image]

I read the following in the [Emacs color-theme Solarized](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users) documentation on the GitHub repository:

> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI
>   version like Cocoa or X11 Emacs), **please please please** consider
>   setting your terminal emulator's colorscheme to use the Solarized
>   palette.
>
> ...
>
> The [Solarized repository](https://github.com/altercation/solarized) includes palettes for some popular terminal
>   emulator as well as Xdefaults; or you can download them from the
>   [official Solarized homepage](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized).
>
> ...
>
> Again, I recommend just changing your terminal colors to Solarized
>   values either manually or via one of the many terminal schemes
>   available for import.

This made me wonder if I am suffering from this problem. However the snapshot above is from Emacs on a **GUI** (Gtk) (i.e. **not** from running Emacs with `-nw` option)

Either way: **How can I change my terminal emulator's colorscheme to use Solarized values?** I have `git cloned` the [solarized repository](https://github.com/altercation/solarized) but I don't know what I am supposed to do with it.

In case it matters:

1. I do not have admin access to the machine where Emacs is installed
2. I am running the latest stable version of Emacs.
3. I connect remotely with `ssh -X` from a `GNOME terminal` from Ubuntu (latest version) on my local machine. GNOME terminal seems to be version `3.6.0ubuntu`.

Comment: I noticed the same in the emacs theme. The contrast is way too low and ruins the theme on my machine as well.

Answer (score -2):

Solorized was initially created for VIM. Mods for other editors weren't written by Ethan Schoonover.
If you look at the full image you posted on the website it says VIM on the top. So basically it works as it should in emacs)  I have tried solorized both on vim and on emacs and I should say it works perfectly fine in VIM.